# The probability that a discrete function is non-decreasing

Tags: probability

> Let $A$ and $B$ be the sets $\{1,2,\dotsc,10\}$ and $\{1,2,\dotsc,20\}$ respectively. Consider a function $A \to B$. What is the probability that the function is non-decreasing?

I know total number of functions possible is $20^{10}$. How to find number of non-decreasing functions?

Comment: Try the same problem replacing 10 by 3 and 20 by 4 and see if you can identify the pattern.

Comment: $$
\frac{1}{20^{10}}\sum_{i_1=1}^{20}\sum_{i_2=i_1}^{20}\sum_{i_3=i_2}^{20} \cdots \sum_{i_{10}=i_9}^{20}1
$$

Comment: omg....what's that giant?

Comment: That's an implicit formulation, but I guess you can work an exact formula out of it.

Comment: please explain...

Comment: For $|B|\gg |A|$, it will be approximately $\frac 1 {|A|!}$

Comment: I guess this has an exact answer.This is from a school level book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted there are $20^{10}$ functions from $A$ to $B$.

We can count the increasing functions with stars and bars.  Use $10$ bars and $20$ stars.   For any arrangement of the stars and bars, we can get a corresponding increasing function from $A$ to $B$  by $f(i)$ is the total number of stars to the left of the $i$-th bar.

For example $**\mid\mid**\mid*\mid ****\mid\mid***\mid\mid*****\mid*\mid **$ corresponds to the increasing function whose respective values on $1, 2,\dots, 10$ are $2,2,4,5,9,9,12,12,17,18$.

Or conversely, the increasing function with respective values $1, 1, 3, 7, 9, 12, 12, 18, 20, 20$ is represented by $*\mid\mid**\mid****\mid**\mid***\mid\mid******\mid**\mid\mid$.

So there are ${30}\choose{10}$ non-decreasing functions from $A$ to $B$.

The probability of randomly selecting a non-decreasing function is $\frac{{30}\choose{10}}{20^{10}}$ (See edit below.  Original answer is incorrect.)

---

Edit: Each string must start with a $*$ (otherwise a function value of $0$ could occur).  So that means there are $19$ (remaining) stars and $10$ bars to place freely.  This changes the probability to $\frac{{29}\choose{10}}{20^{10}}$.

Thank you to A.S. for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\binom {|A|+|B|-1}{|A|}$ as you seem to have overcounted cases where there is a bar to the left of the left-most star.

Comment: @ A.S. You're right.  One has to start with a $*$. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Or just add one less star to the arrangement and start counting $B$ from $0$.

Comment: The normal way to set up the stars and bars is to set up one bar less than the number of "distinct options". This is because you only need $n-1$ bars to create $n$ sections.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an equivalent formulation of your problem. Choose 10 samples, $\{X_1,\dots,X_{10}\}$ independently from a uniform probability distribution among the numbers $\{1,2,\dots,20\}$. What is the probability that $X_1\leq\dots\leq X_{10}$?

Since the $X_i$ are independent this is just $P(X_1\leq X_2)\cdot P(X_1\leq X_2)\cdots P(X_9\leq X_{10})$. Then since $P(X_i\leq X_{i+1})=P(X_i\geq X_{i+1})$ by symmetry (they are independently chosen from the same distribution) and $1=P(X_i\leq X_{i+1})+P(X_i> X_{i+1})$ (they are disjoint events making up all possibilities) $1=(X_i\leq X_{i+1})+P(X_i\geq X_{i+1})-P(X_i=X_{i+1})=2P(X_i\leq X_{i+1})-\frac{1}{20}.$ Rearranging, $P(X_i\leq X_{i+1})=\frac{21}{40}$. Therefore, the probability that the $X_i$s are nondecreasing is $\left(\frac{21}{40}\right)^9$ or roughly $0.303$%

Comment: I don't think this is right. For instance $P(X_1 \leq X_2 \cap X_2 \leq X_3)=P(X_2 - X_1 \geq 0 \cap X_3 - X_2 \geq 0)$. $X_2 - X_1$ and $X_3 - X_2$ are not independent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, using generating functions.

Let $m$ be the size of $A$ and $n$ be the size of $B$.

Let $P_m(n)$ be the number of non-decreasing functions from $A$ to $B$.

The first element can be any out of $m$. After choosing it, the remaining terms must also be a non-decreasing sequence. This leads to the recurrence relation

$$P_m(n)=\sum_{k=1}^nP_{m-1}(k)$$

Now let $f_n(x)=nx+\sum_{m=2}^\infty x^mP_m(n)$, where we have incorporated the fact that $P_1(n)=n$.

The recurrence relation for $P$ leads to a recurrence relation for $f$ which is

$$f_n(x)=nx+x\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x).$$

Now, let $g(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)y^n$. The recurrence relation for $f$ allows us to find that

$$g(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(1-y)(1-x-y)}$$.

Comment: I think you intend $P_n(m)=\sum_{k=1}^m P_{n-1}(k)$. (At each step you always remove exactly one element of $A$ and possibly some elements of $B$ from the problem.)

Comment: ops, I had $m$ and $n$ reversed. Sorry.

Comment: But now how do $f$ and $g$ answer the question?

Comment: If you expand $g(x,y)$ in a power series (using a computer), the coefficient of $x^my^n$ will be the desired quantity, $P_m(n)$.